# How can we import a specific variable from other makefile without creating additional makefile with defining required variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can we import a specific variable from other makefile without creating additional makefile with defining required variable.

I found  few solutions which tells to create new makefile with required variable and include it. I dont want to create a new makefile. I just want to include only one particular variable from other makefile to my main make file. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want to create a new makefile.

Actually, I really much advise you to do so.

However, if that's desperately needed, then do:

```
$(eval $(shell $(MAKE) -pf /some/other/Makefile | grep '^some_var ='))
$(info Now 'some_var' is (hopefully) set and equal to $(some_var))
```

Comment: Hi Matt, It means parsing the whole makefile and getting the variable? Is yes, it would not look good In my opinion. Is there any other option other than this method ?

Comment: @santosh There can be no way to get variable's value _from file_ without some sort of _file parsing_. And, in general, one must complete _the whole_ make's first pass to make sure the value is right. Of course, you can simply omit "make" step and eval/grep for that "raw line" in Makefile directly. However, this is _very_ dirty, and could be broken pretty easily.

Comment: Just to expand on @Matt's point, what if your variable was set like: `some_var = $(other_var)/foo/bar` ??  How can you get that value without parsing the entire makefile so that `other_var` is set?  Or maybe `some_var` is set multiple times.  Or maybe it's set different ways inside a makefile conditional (`ifeq` etc.) how can you know which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

Another (also terrible option) if you HAVE to do this and you can edit both makefiles is:

If you want value of variable VAR_A from makefileA in makefileB you could

makefileA:

```
SOMTHING=1
VAR_A=$(SOMTHING)

# Rule to print var A
.PHONY: get_var_a
get_var_a:
    @echo $(VAR_A)
```

makefileB:

```
# Set the variable by calling make makefileA with the target to get the value of 
# VAR_A
VAR_A='$(shell echo make -f makefileA get_var_a)'
```

But it would really be better to have some common makefile that you just include in both...

**Example of Common Makefile**

common.mk:

```
LIST1=a c e g i k
LIST2=b d f h j l
VAR_A=$(sort $(LIST1) $(LIST2) $(EXRTA_ITEMS))
```

makefile_a.mk:

```
# Prefix with '-' if you don't want the makefile to fail if common.mk 
# can't be found
-include common.mk
$(info makefile_A VAR_A = $(VAR_A))
```

makefile_b.mk:

```
# Add some extra items into VAR_A by popuulating this variable
EXRTA_ITEMS = m n o p

# No prefix here - so if common.mk can't be found then its an error
include common.mk
$(info makefile_A VAR_A = $(VAR_A))
```

So here, both makefiles include common.mk - which does some processing to generate a variable called `VAR_A` and both makefiles can make use of it and even add to it if they know which variables VAR_A is made of.

Effectivly including `common.mk` is like copy-pasting it inside your makefile.

Comment: Can you please give some example of having common makefile ?

Comment: Updated for you... not really sure how you want to use it exactly so I tried to makeup an example that covers a few methods